# "Unreveal" modal using Zurb Foundation

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation on a site, and I was trying to get a modal window working with the Reveal JS Plugin. I see that you can add a `dismissModalClass` option to the parameters that you pass to `reveal()` that will attach an event handler to a button, etc. that will close the modal on click.

Is there a way to manually close the modal window with Reveal? I would like to be able to attach a close method to different custom events.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could simply trigger the click dynamically in an other event by doing something like this

```
$('.close-reveal-modal','#myModal').click()
```

**UPDATE**

After looking through the source code of the plugin, it looks like they bind an event to the modal element called `reveal:close`. So you can also do something like this

```
$('.otherClose').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close')
})​
```

**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BY7ZF/5/)**

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but if the Reveal plugin doesn't have it built in, it doesn't have it built in. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Updated the answer with a more elegant solution i think :)

Comment: That is perfect. I would double-accept your answer if I could!

Comment: why not suggest the unreveal to zurb dev team?

Comment: Be carefull, unlike first solution, `trigger('reveal:close')` is not using lock, so you can face race conditions

Comment: I'm having trouble returning control to the parent view when the modal is closed.  Perhaps you can help me.  My question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49161370/1735836

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the following:

```
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
```

Comment: This is true in Foundation 4, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use their jQuery plugin jquery.foundation.reveal.js

```
 $('#mymModal').reveal({
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //class name of button to close open dialog
        }
    });
```