# Zurb Foundation 4 closed modal gets stuck

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have a modal popup which contains a View Details button that opens a different modal popup.  I'm using `$('#modalName').foundation('reveal', 'close')` everywhere and it works very well.  But in this case, I believe there is an event issue going on, because the modal closes but control never returns to the window.

[image: Stuck view]

This is the modal I want to close:

[image: Popup view]

Notice the red box around the Done button and the X (close).  I want the same code to execute no matter which way the user closes the popup.

### CSHTML

```
@*The Modal View for Displaying Meter Tag Details*@
<div id="meterTagDetailsModal" class="reveal-modal medium">
    <div class="row modalTitleRow">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h3>
                Meter Tags Details
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="row meterRow">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <table id="meterTagDetailsTable" class="meterTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Meter Name</th>
                        <th>Commodity</th>
                        <th>Building Name</th>
                        <th>Site</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
        <a id="closeModal" class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row meterRow">
        <div class="small-12 columns text-right">
            <a class="button tiny" onclick="$('#closeModal').click()">Done</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

**Bind event**

```
$('#meterTagDetailsModal').on("closed", onCloseMeterTagDetails);
```

**Method**

```
onCloseMeterTagDetails = function () {
    $('#meterTagDetailsModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    $('#meterTagDetailsModal').trigger('reveal: close');
}
```

**Execution gets into this method when the popup closes.  But the view is stuck in limbo.  I've tried both of the statements shown.**

Does anybody know how I can get the view to close and return control to the window?

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'll try!  Thank you.

Comment: Very firstly check if control is getting into function: `onCloseMeterTagDetails` or not.
Try putting `console.log('test')` within above function